# Images are not showing in the login view after logging out

Tags: codeigniter

[This is the actual login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMo6I.png)

[The 2nd pic is when the user logs out or has validation errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xCJN.png)

And this is my current code

```
 <?php
        echo form_open('login/validate_credentials');
        echo '<img src="img/too.png" style="height: 30px">'.form_input( 'username', '');
        echo '<img src="img/pwd.png" style="height: 30px">'.form_password('password', '');
        echo '<br>';
        echo form_submit('submit', 'Login');
        echo form_close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use HTml Helper to display [images](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/html_helper.html#img)

```
        echo form_open('login/validate_credentials');
        echo img(array('src' => 'img/too.png', 'height' => '30px')) . form_input( 'username', '');
        echo img(array('src' => 'img/pwd.png', 'height' => '30px')) .form_password('password', '');
        echo '<br>';
        echo form_submit('submit', 'Login');
        echo form_close();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>login/validate_credentials">
     <img src="<?php echo base_url('imagepath');" style="height: 30px">
     <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="">
     <img src="img/pwd.png" style="height: 30px">
     <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="">
     <input type="submit" name="Login">
```